# Whatsapp-web js send video "Error: Evaluation failed: R"

Tags: node.js, whatsapp

I've error as in below when I try to send mp4 file send with `whatsapp-web js`. How can I send mp4 file with whatsapp-web js I couldnt find any solution to my issue. When I try with the image this process everythings works but when I use mp4 file I couldnt send

This is my code:

```
const qrcode = require('qrcode-terminal');
const util = require('util')
const fs = require('fs')

const { Client, LocalAuth, MessageMedia } = require('whatsapp-web.js');

const client = new Client({
    authStrategy: new LocalAuth({ clientId: "example" }),
    puppeteer: {
        headless: true,
        args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox', '--remote-debugging-port=9222'],
        executablePath: '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome',
    }

});
 
 

client.on('qr', qr => {
    qrcode.generate(qr, {small: true});
});

client.on('ready', async ()  =>  {
    console.log('Client is ready!');
    const number = "TEST_NUMBER";


   const videodata = await ReadVideo("example.mp4")
   var VideoMessage = new MessageMedia('video/mp4',videodata)
   // Getting chatId from the number.
    // we have to delete "+" from the beginning and add "@c.us" at the end of the number.
   const chatId = number.substring(1) + "@c.us";
  
   // Sending message.
   client.sendMessage(chatId, VideoMessage);


});

async function ReadVideo(filename){
    return await util.promisify(fs.readFile)(filename,'base64');
  
  }

client.initialize();
```

And this is the error message:

```
  Client is ready!
    /Users/duygu/JS_Projects/WhatsAppWebAPI/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/ExecutionContext.js:221
                throw new Error('Evaluation failed: ' + helper_js_1.helper.getExceptionMessage(exceptionDetails));
                      ^
    
    Error: Evaluation failed: R
        at ExecutionContext._evaluateInternal (/Users/duygu/JS_Projects/WhatsAppWebAPI/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/ExecutionContext.js:221:19)
        at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
        at async ExecutionContext.evaluate (/Users/duygu/JS_Projects/WhatsAppWebAPI/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/ExecutionContext.js:110:16)
        at async Client.sendMessage (/Users/duygu/JS_Projects/WhatsAppWebAPI/node_modules/whatsapp-web.js/src/Client.js:686:28)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be that you encode it base64 with the `readFile` func and then `MessageMedia` encodes it too.

If you find another solution let me know please.